# Where is Person and not Person::Single

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Lets say I have three Classes

```
Person

Person::Single < Person

Person::Married < Person
```

Lets say I have **two** Persons that are Single => `Person::Single`

Then i get two Persons when I do:

```
Person.all.count
=> 2
```

**But my goal is to get only the persons that are type `Person` and not `Person::Single` or `Person::Married`**

What I tried is:

```
Person.where(type: Person.to_s)
=> 2
```

but this also returns `2` because `Person::Single` and `Person::Married` inherit from `Person`

**What can I do instead?** 
Is there for example an way to say that `::Single` and `::Married` have the same methods from `person` but are not the same type? Thanks

Comment: does `Person.where(type: nil)` work?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is marked with the rails tag, I assume your Person class is an *ActiveRecord* model. There is some more information missing, but I will just assume where I don't really know ;)

Your Person class inherits the **ActiveRecord** methods, for example "all", and **Person::Single** (and **::Maried**) will inherit it through Person.

So, naturally, when you do a Person.all it will just do the regular **[<#ActiveRecord>.all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html)** method, which does not know and not care about ::Single and ::Maried.

What you can do is dynamically setting the [default_scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope), based on the class name of which you are calling .all, or .where or whatever on.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def self.default_scope
    scope = if self.name == Person.sti_name
      where(:type => Person.sti_name)
    else
      nil
    end

    scope
  end
 end
```

This will also scope your where(:whatever => x) queries.

**However, this is asuming you have an attribute called "type" for you Person model (column in database).**

**EDIT:** As Holger pointed out, there is already magic involved with rails STI. I still think it is viable to set a default scope, only you should skip setting the scopes for single and married.
If you don't need it as a default scope, you should just try `Person.where(:type => Person.sti_name)` or `Person.where(:type => Person.name)` since rails asserts the class name to sti_name if the class inherits from ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: The `type` column is special by default in Rails as it takes part in [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance). As such, you have to work with this mechanism instead of building your own scopes. Your answer is not compatible with the STI model in Rails. And yes, Rails does indeed care very much about sub-classes with STI.

Comment: @Holger Ah, indeed the type column is special. Thanks for pointing this out to me, I wasn't really aware of that. However, that should not effect the solution and I don't see why it "is not compatible" with the STI model, since all you do is setting scopes for the subclasses...

Comment: For one, Rails stores the name of the subclass in the `type` column, by default including the full namespace. So it will be either "`Person::Single"`, `"Person::Married"`, or `"Person"`. The values thus differ strictly. Also, the returned objects are of the child type if defined. The scopes you proposed thus make things much more brittle and un-obvious.

Comment: Edited. Since John Smith only wanted to have his superclass scoped, the solution does not break anything (btw, neither did my old solution, it still would have returned the subclass instances, but yeah it was like overriding rails magic with less developed bs ;).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Person.where(:type => Person).count
```